# Linking numpy with homebrew

Tags: opencv, numpy

In order to run OpenCV with python numpy is required. When I type `brew install numpy` in the terminal, it says numpy is already installed, it's just not linked. To link numpy, `brew link numpy` is typed in the terminal. However, this gives the following error message:

> Error: Could not symlink lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew-numpy-nose.pth /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages is not writable.

Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7/`

Comment: @cel that command looks so wrong to a linux user...

Comment: @ali_m, is it that bad? Seems somewhat correct to me. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @cel On Linux `/usr/local/lib` contains system libraries, so messing with permissions there would be asking for trouble. My understanding is that nothing else uses `/usr/local/lib` on Macs, so it should be fine. It just evokes a gut reaction in me...

Comment: @ali_m, yes on mac things are different. `/usr/local` is used by `homebrew` as a prefix. For that to work everything has to be owned by the user.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already install a copy of numpy in the python. Try to uninstall it and relink the brewed numpy:
if it installs to both python2.7 and python3 site-packages remove python2 package with.

```
sudo -H pip2 uninstall numpy  
brew link numpy
```

if any deviation try :

```
brew install numpy --with-python3 --without-python.
```

and link again.